# Dynamic column header in data table from JSON array?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, json, html, jquery

I want to populate data table with dynamic column header and column data,  I can populate dynamic column data successfully, but I can't achieve dynamic column...

I am using JSON array.

My **html** code is:

```
 <body>
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="1">
    </table>
 </body>
```

My **JavaScript** code is.

```
  <script>
  var JSONResult = '{
     "column1":"data1",
     "column2":"data2",
     "column3":"data3",
     "columnN":"dataN"}';
  var row_dtable = new Array();
  var dtable_api = $('#example').dataTable();
  $.each(JSONResult , function(key, value) {
         row_dtable.push(value);
       }); 
  dtable_api.api().row.add( row_dtable ).draw( false );   
  </script>
```

Comment: How this is GIS related?

Comment: I am developing this application in ol3, resultant  column will get from geojson file.

Comment: what errors or issues do you get?

Answer (score 1):

this is a little late but i think you are missing some tags.
change this :

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="1">
</table>
```

to this :

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="1">
   <thead></thead>
   <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```